# Java NullPointerException when trying to save/update to MySQL DB via Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Preface:
Trying to save/update to a mysql database via springboot. Getting a null pointer exception in when trying to access the DAOImpl class:

Here is the entity class:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="tracker")
public class Tracker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name="link")
    private String link;

    public Tracker() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tracker{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", text='" + text + '\'' +
                ", link='" + link + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Here is the DAO Class:

```
import com.example.Tracker;

import java.util.List;

public interface DAO {

    public List<Tracker> getItems();

    public void saveItems(String text, String link);

    public Tracker getItem(int theId);

    public void deleteItem(int theId);

}
```

Here is the implement class of the DAO class:

```
package com.example.tracker.dao;

import com.example.tracker.entity.Tracker;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class DOAImpl implements DAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Tracker> getItems() {
        //To-Do
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveItems(String text, String link) {
        Tracker item = new Tracker();
        System.out.println(text);
        System.out.println(link);
        item.setLink(link);
        item.setText(text);
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Tracker getItems(int theId) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteItem(int theId) {
        //To-Do
    }
}
```

Here is the class that does the work:

```
package com.example.WebScrapper;

import com.example.dao.DOAImpl;
import com.example.entity.Tracker;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class itemScraper {
    private String baseURL = "https://www.example-page.com/page/";
    private int page = 1;

    @Autowired
    private DOAImpl itemDOA;

    WebScraper itemScraper = new WebScraper();

    public String getAllPages() throws IOException {
        while(true){
            String webpage = baseURL + page;
            itemScraper.setWebURL(webpage);
            itemScraper.getWebReturn();
            HashMap pageItems = itemScraper.getElements();
            Iterator iterator = pageItems.entrySet().iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry currentItem = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                itemDOA.saveItems((String) currentItem.getKey(), (String) currentItem.getValue());
                System.out.println("Item Saved");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When the itemDAO.saveItems is called, this is when the null pointer is thrown. I have checked, and the currentItem value and key are present. But getting a null pointer thrown. So, not sure why I'm getting this issue, any help is appreciated.

StackTrace for context:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.WebScrapper.itemScraper.getAllPages(ExampleScraper.java:37)
    at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace errors ?

Comment: What is line 37 of ExampleScraper?

Comment: Where's `itemScraper` specified as a Spring bean? Maybe, you're just missing `@Component` over that class.

Comment: sorry to say this, but your code is really bad. Classes should start with capital letters, not like itemScraper. You instanciate a class Webscraper inside your class itemScraper and name the instance itemScraper as the containing class.. You should clean up first, to make it easy for people to read your code, if you'd like to get help. Post all of your classes which appear in that stacktrace, mark the line numbers for which exceptions ar thrown..

Comment: @juwil I was going to say it too

Answer (score 0):

So, although I wasn't getting any errors with my HibernateConfig class that was setting up my Session Factory, after some some additional testing, it turns out the null pointer was because the database connection didn't exist. Strange that I was only getting that error once I was trying to send to the database and not on startup when it's supposed to create the connection.